# How do you run each "tick" of the program in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

What I mean by "tick" is, "each time the program 'updates', or essentially each frame when it runs". Like the Gamemaker `Step` event for objects. Gamemaker is just bad because these "ticks" or "steps" are directly tied to fps, which can break the game, quite literally.

This is probably a repeated question because I simply don't know what to ask for. If it is, please go ahead and point me in the right direction by giving me the proper terminology for this program. Perhaps there is no "step" in Android Studio, and I just need to have a `TimerTask` to have my game constantly update and do its actions.

Why do I want to know? Because some actions the AI takes needs to be happening regardless of user input, like in an RTS game. Or for updating your position on a map, that's tied to Google Services' `getLastLocation` method.

Comment: Android Studio is an IDE, it doesn't have any ticks or game loops or anything. You're just using Android. And for that you'll make your own timer, unless you're using a framework that provides one, like OpenGL ES on the lowest level.

Comment: OK. That's what I thought. Should I have the loop that will effectively be my "step" in the onResume method?

Comment: This is a old Google IO video on Real Time Games but may be helpful: https://youtu.be/U4Bk5rmIpic

Comment: I appreciate it. I'll look through that as soon as I wake up tomorrow.